# Getting exception'System.LimitException: awduplicate2:Too many SOQL queries: 101'.' while updating records through data loader

Tags: apex, trigger, data-loader, bulkification

I was trying to upload 1000 records through data loader. On updates a trigger will be fired to update few fields on lead .

```
trigger TotalReachout on Task (after update)
{

  List<String> usrIdLst = new List<String>();
  List<String> LeadIdLst = new List<String>();

  Map<String, Boolean> userMap = new Map<String, Boolean>();
  Map<String, Decimal> LeadEmailMap = new Map<String, Decimal>();
  Map<String, Decimal> LeadCallMap = new Map<String, Decimal>();

  for(Task task:Trigger.New){
      usrIdLst.add(task.CreatedById);
      LeadIdLst.add(task.WhoId);
  }

  List<User> usrLst = [SELECT Id, DR_rep__c from USER where Id IN:usrIdLst];
  List<Lead> LeadLst = [SELECT Id, Email_Reachout__c,Call_Reachout__c from Lead where id IN:LeadIdLst];

  for(User objUsr : usrLst)
  {
      userMap.put(objUsr.Id,objUsr.DR_rep__c);

  }

  for(Lead objLd : LeadLst)
  {
      LeadEmailMap.put(objLd.Id,objLd.Email_Reachout__c);
      LeadCallMap.put(objLd.Id,objLd.Call_Reachout__c);
  }

  for(Task task:Trigger.New){

         Lead objLead = new Lead();
         objLead.Id = task.WhoId;
         if((userMap.get(task.CreatedById) == true) && (task.Subject.contains('Message Sent')))
         {       

             system.debug('lead.Email_Reachout__c'+LeadEmailMap.get(task.WhoId));
             if(LeadEmailMap.get(task.WhoId)==null){
             objLead.Email_Reachout__c=1;

             }else{
                objLead.Email_Reachout__c=LeadEmailMap.get(task.WhoId)+1;
            }
         }

         if((userMap.get(task.CreatedById) == true) && (task.Subject.contains('Call')))
         {

             system.debug('objLead.Call_Reachout__c'+LeadCallMap.get(task.WhoId));
             if(LeadCallMap.get(task.WhoId)==null){
                 objLead.Call_Reachout__c=1;

             }else{
                objLead.Call_Reachout__c=LeadCallMap.get(task.WhoId)+1;
             }
         }

         update objLead;
     }

}
```

when i update till 5 records it is updating fine,but when i update more than 50 to 1000 it's thoroughgoing above exception.

```
   Any updates in the code are appreciable....   thanks
```

Comment: Given that your Task trigger is updating Leads, any "before update, after update" Triggers you have for Leads will also fire.  It looks like between these objects (and possibly more) you've got too many SOQL statements.  Check your Lead Triggers to make sure they are sufficiently bulkified.  Maybe post them here as well?

Answer (score 3):

Well the first thing I noticed was you are doing a DML inside of a loop which has tighter restrictions than SOQL queries.

```
for (Task tsk: Trigger.new)
{
  ...
  update objLead;
}
```

Put these in a a List and update the whole list at once.

```
List<Lead> objLeads = new List<Lead>();
for (Task tsk: Trigger.new)
{
  ...
  objLeads.add(objLead);
}
update objLeads;
```

I don't see where you would be hitting the SOQL query limit here, but it's likely in your Lead triggers since each iteration of that loop will call a new iteration of the triggers.  So, even if your lead triggers are bulkified, they likely will still hit this limit but I'm guessing there is something not bulkified with SOQL queries since you didn't hit the DML limits first.